# Python: How to update multiple address lines

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a banking system for Uni using Python. I'm new to Python and programming so I can get confused about a lot of things fairly easy, so I apologise in advance if I call things by the wrong word.

I have 5 modules: `Person`, `Account`, `Customer`, `Admin`, and `bank_system`.

My issue is trying to update the address. I used similar code from updating the name but the problem with that is that name is only one word. Which causes problems because the address is stored as 4 separate pieces, as you can see in the `__init__` method. The method to actually update the address is in the `run_profile_options()` method located near the bottom.

This is how I want the address to print after I enter an updated address (with Red House, Red Drive, Redplace, F11 1FF).

```
Your Profile Settings Options Are:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1) Update name
2) Update address
3) Print details
4) Back

Choose your option: 3
Name Adam:
Address: 14
         Wilcot Street
         Bath
         B5 5RT

Account balance: 5000.00
```

Working with what I have already python returns this when updating the address.

```
Your Profile Settings Options Are:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1) Update name
2) Update address
3) Print details
4) Back

Choose your option: 2

 Please enter a new address
: Red House, Red Drive, Red Place, F11 1FF

Your Profile Settings Options Are:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1) Update name
2) Update address
3) Print details
4) Back

Choose your option: 3
Name Adam:
Address: R
         e
         d


Account balance: 5000.00
```

What would I have to do to be able to update the individual lines?

Here is the full module:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, password, address = [None, None, None, None]):
        #PERSON DETAILS
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.address = address

    def get_address(self):
        #SEARCHING PERSON ADDRESS
        return self.address

    def update_name(self, name):
        #UPDATING PERSON NAME
        self.name = name

    def update_address(self, address):
        #UPDATING PERSON ADDRESS
        self.address = address

    def get_name(self):
        #SEARCHING PERSON NAME
        return self.name

    def print_details(self):
        #PRINTING PERSON DETAILS
        print("Name %s:" %self.name)
        print("Address: %s" %self.address[0])
        print("         %s" %self.address[1])
        print("         %s" %self.address[2])
        print("         %s" %self.address[3])
        print(" ")

    def check_password(self, password):
        #PASSWORD VALIDITY CHECK
        if self.password == password:
            return True
        return False

    def profile_settings_menu(self):
        #PERSON PROFILE MENU
         print (" ")
         print ("Your Profile Settings Options Are:")
         print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
         print ("1) Update name")
         print ("2) Update address")
         print ("3) Print details")
         print ("4) Back")
         print (" ")
         option = int(input ("Choose your option: "))
         return option

    def run_profile_options(self):
        #PERSON PROFILE CHOICE
        loop = 1           
        while loop == 1:
            choice = self.profile_settings_menu()
            if choice == 1:
                #UPDATING NAME
                name=input("\n Please enter new name\n: ")
                self.update_name(name)
            elif choice == 2:
                #UPDATING ADDRESS
                address=input("\n Please enter a new address\n: ")
                self.update_address(address)
            elif choice == 3:
                #PRINTING OWN DETAILS
                self.print_details()
            elif choice == 4:
                #GO BACK
                loop = 0
```

Comment: Post the preferred/returned output as part of the question. Don't link to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is arguably in your `update_address()` method. Currently, an updated address is not split into a list of four address pieces as your `address` instance variable seems to expect. Instead, you store it as one plain string. Then, when you print the address, you are actually printing the first few characters of the address string instead of the first few elements of the address list.

So you first need to choose the method in `Person` that should be responsible for splitting the address into pieces. You could do it in `run_profile_options()` before passing the address to `update_address()` or you could do it in `update_address()`.

If you choose the former, you need to update `run_profile_options()` by adding this line:

```
[address_part.strip() for address_part in address.split(',')]
```

Afterward, `run_profile_options()` should look like this:

```
def run_profile_options(self):
    # ...
    while loop == 1:
        # ...
        elif choice == 2:
            address = input("\n Please enter a new address\n: ")
            # Split the address into four parts.
            address = [address_part.strip() for address_part in address.split(',')]
            self.update_address(address)
```

If you choose the latter, you'll instead need to add that line of code to `update_address()`:

```
def update_address(self, address):
    # Split the address into four parts.
    self.address = [address_part.strip() for address_part in address.split(',')]
```

Note that the code that splits the address into pieces assumes that each piece is delimited by a comma character. If this will ever not be the case, then you'll need to update my code to account for some other delimiter.